# Attempt to present <CFSDK.CFViewController> on <UINavigationController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new in swift and I am Implementing Cash Free Api Whose process is like this

```
https://dev.cashfree.com/payment-gateway/integrations/mobile-integration/ios
```

But I am facing problem while presenting CFViewController it is showing warning

```
Attempt to present <CFSDK.CFViewController> on <UINavigationController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My code is like this

```
CFPaymentService().doWebCheckoutPayment(
                        params: self.getPaymentParams(),
                        env: "PROD",
                        callback: self)
```

While Parameter are

```
func getPaymentParams() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
        return [
            "orderId": OrderIdForCashFree,
            "appId": CashFreeAPIKeyFromServer,
            "tokenData" : cftoken,
            "orderAmount": AmountExpectedforServer,
            "customerName": customerNameCashFree,
            "orderNote": orderNoteCashFree,
            "orderCurrency": "INR",
            "customerPhone": customerPhoneCashFree,
            "customerEmail": customerEmailCashFree,
            "notifyUrl": ""
        ]
    }
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

The warning reads better like this -

```
Attempt to present <CFSDK.CFViewController> 
on <UINavigationController>
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Seems like you are calling this method way too early - maybe in `viewDidLoad()`

```
CFPaymentService().doWebCheckoutPayment(
    params: self.getPaymentParams(),
    env: "PROD",
    callback: self
)
```

If the view is not properly set up yet, you will receive this warning from `UIKit`. What you can do is -

1. Initiate this call from a button tap. /// Recommended (same as a user would interact with it in the app)
2. Delay the call by some time say **0.5 seconds** or **1 second**. /// Lazy - for testing purpose only

Both of these will make sure that view has had enough time to show up (before the call is initiated) and the warning will go away.

Comment: I am calling API on button click In API response I'm calling this code I even delay for 2 second but problem is still the same.

Comment: You need to make sure that when this call initiates after your own API call, the screen represented by `self` is visible to you and not covered by any other `UIViewController` instance. You can try reproducing this issue in their sample app - https://github.com/cashfree/ios-CFWebSDK. If it's there, you can raise a bug / contact support etc.

Comment: I tried everything still the issue is same